# Deploy React Js app on Apache Server Linux environment

Tags: apache, reactjs, .htaccess

I am able to deploy react app on apache server, to login and the home page displays. All links work properly.

The problem occurs when I refresh the page (using F5). It says:

> The requested URL /home was not found on this server.

I did almost everything like RewriteEngine set to On in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `.htaccess` seems okay, but it might be ignored by Apache.

You should

1. Check if `AllowOverride` is set to `All` for the Directory you're serving the website from (in your Apache vhost configuration file, under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`)
2. Check if the `rewrite` mod is enabled (enable it with `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, then restart Apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`)